# Drupal location module shows only a portion of Gmap on node page

Tags: google-maps, drupal, module, drupal-7, location

When first loaded on a node page, Location form shows only a portion of the map as seen [here](http://screencast.com/t/MS0Zd43K). However, as soon as I resize browser window, or click on the map, then the map displays properly full width. Any one knows of this issue and could give me a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is said in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#constructor_1) that

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size

You need to trigger the resize event after your page is load like:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```